# Hudson build is using old jars

Tags: java, maven-2, hudson

Hey guys. So I have in Hudson 2 Java/Maven/SVN projects. Let's call them A and B. B depends on A. I sometimes commit code for them simultaneously. Hudson is smart enough to queue the build of B until the build for A is done. However when it does build B it uses an older build (jar). Sometimes several builds/days old. Then B fails because of unknown symbols (new classes/methods in A).
I tried to wipe workspace and order a build manually. Same thing. The older build is used. What can I do to force Hudson to use the latest jars build by itself. I haven't tried deleting all previous builds yet but seems an extreme solution. Hopefully it won't be required.

Comment: How do you have Hudson configured to find the jars?

Comment: I didn't do any special configuration. I'm guessing the dependency was pulled from the POM file so A appears as an upstream project in B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your dependent artifacts as snapshots (which you should be) consider setting the maven goal to

```
clean deploy -U
```

This forces maven to update all snapshots.

Comment: This works wonderfully! Thanks! Should have thought about it. I was so busy thinking that it's a Hudson problem when it was actually a Maven thing.

Comment: Just an FYI: I found out (the hard way) that snapshot artifacts expire after one day. if you have two commits for one day, see solution above. If you are building offline, make sure the snapshot artifacts are not older than 1 day. You can trick maven buy changing the timestamp of the artifacts (I think it is the `touch` command in Unix).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven for your builds are you using the deploy or install targets?  If so you should be able to look at the logs and see that the jar in the repository is being updated. If it is up to date, then your pom.xml configuration is likely to be incorrect.

Comment: Both projects use "clean deploy" for build and I can confirm that the jar for A was properly uploaded. I doubt that there's a pom problem in B because if I wait 1-2 days and ask it to re-build (without any commit or change in the meantime) it will build properly.